# Angular UI Router ignoring HTML5 Mode off

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Angular UI Router is ignoring HTML5Mode(false), and it's rendering links in a way that can't be bookmarked or directly landing upon:

app.js:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('search', {
      url: '/search',
      views: {
        'main.wrapper': {
          templateUrl: 'views/search.html',
          controller: 'SearchCtrl'
        },
        'navbar': { templateUrl: 'views/search.navbar.html' }
      });

$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
```

foo.html:

```
<a ui-sref="search">Search</a>
```

Becomes

```
<a href="/search">Search</a>
```

Shouldn't it detect it's not on HTML5 Mode and return

```
<a href="/#/search">Search</a>
```

Comment: This is a known and reported issue. Check quick fix here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1397

Comment: Use the pre-release version 0.2.12-pre1 for now.  http://bit.ly/UIR-0212pre1 ... it has a few fixes for 1.3.0 compat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by [Radim Köhler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679310/radim-k%C3%B6hler), this is a bug between `angular-ui-router ~0.2.11` and `angular 1.3.0`.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1397