# ui-router not producing correct href attribute in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
$stateProvider
  .state('admin', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/admin',
    template: '<div ui-view></div>'
  })


<a ui-sref="admin">admin</a>
```

The url I get is `<a href="/admin">admin</a>` when it *should* be `/#/admin` -- this breaks when I command click on a link to open in a new tab.

Comment: Are you using Angular 1.3?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, reported as a bug. Will be fixed in next release. Here is a workaround:

#### [Impossible to disable html5Mode with angular 1.3.0-rc.3 #1397](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1397)

> Due to:
>
> [angular/angular.js@dc3de7f](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/dc3de7fb7a14c38b5c3dc7decfafb0b51d422dd1)
>
> the html5mode-check in urlRouter.js [line 383] is no longer correct. And thus it's impossible to disable html5mode.
>
> A quick fix could be:

```
var isHtml5 = $locationProvider.html5Mode();
if (angular.isObject(isHtml5)) {
  isHtml5 = isHtml5.enabled;
}
```

Also there is suggestion by [Chris T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3225368/chris-t) *(`UI-Router` team member)* - see comments under this [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26399911/1679310)

> Use the pre-release version 0.2.12-pre1 for now. [bit.ly/UIR-0212pre1](http://bit.ly/UIR-0212pre1) ... it has a few fixes for 1.3.0 compat. –  Chris T Oct 16 at 16:13

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the `html5Mode` in [$locationProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider):

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Also, I found this issue, it may be related (I don't know which version you are using):

[Impossible to disable html5Mode with angular 1.3.0-rc.3](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1397)

Comment: I don't want to use html5mode, as that requires rewrites on server side.

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26220037/2056394) looks similar, shouldn't you being affected by the same bug?